# Finding the range of the two-variable function $f(x,y) = 2 + \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm required to determine analytically the range of the following function:

[$f(x,y) = 2 + \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0igU.png)

The domain for this function is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 ≤ 9\}$. I've found that the range for a very similar function (which is $f(x,y) = \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$) is $\{z | 0 ≤ 2 ≤ 3\}\implies \text{Range} = [0,3].$

However, I'm not sure if that same range applies to the first function. I have some confusion in that case. Could someone please help me find the range of this function?

Thank you

Comment: If you know range set $A$ for some $f$ function, then range for $f+const.$ will be $A+const.$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are overthinking this. If I tell you that I have some real number $z$ such that $0\le z\le 3$ then what can you say about $2+z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x, y) = \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$

You found the range, which is $[0, 3]$

Then $f(x, y) = g(x, y) + 2$

The graph of $g$ is just the graph of $f$ but there is a translation in the positive $z$ direction by 2. Therefore, the range of $f$ becomes $[2, 5]$.

The domain of the two functions are the same, because the restriction is because the expression within the square root cannot be negative. That expression doesn't change, so the domain does not impact the range either.

Comment: Your explanation helps me a lot. Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

The function $f\left(x,y\right)=2+\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$ represents an upper hemisphere centered at (0,0,2) with a radius of 3. This means the range of $f\left(x,y\right)$ is $\left[2,5\right]$.